# How to intercept/peek in an Immutable.js Map- or List chain

Tags: immutable.js

Sometimes my Redux selectors are quite complicated. I need some means for debugging each step in the chain.

Here is a simplified selector as an example:

```
export const selectCompletedFilesForSaveToServer = state => {
  return state
    .getIn(['file', 'saveToServerQueue'])
    .filterNot(item => item.get('isPosting'))
    .valueSeq();
};
```

And this is what I want to do:

```
export const selectCompletedFilesForSaveToServer = state => {
  return state
    .getIn(['file', 'saveToServerQueue'])
    .intercept(item => console.log(item.toJS())
    .filterNot(item => item.get('isPosting'))
    .intercept(item => console.log(item.toJS())
    .valueSeq();
};
```

I.e. the intercept function should take whatever collection is thrown at it (Map, List, etc), iterate over the collection and then return the original collection for further chaining.

I tried to use .forEach(), but I didn't understand how it works.

My current solution is to manually break up the chain into separate intermediate variables for inspection, but this is not a nice solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. while writing my question I kind of got some perspective and solved it.

The .filter() function essentially is a peek function. Just remember to return true..

```
export const selectCompletedFilesForSaveToServer = state => {
  return state
    .getIn(['file', 'saveToServerQueue'])
    .filter(item => {
      console.log(item.toJS());
      return true;
    });
    .filterNot(item => item.get('isPosting'))
    .filter(item => {
      console.log(item.toJS());
      return true;
    });
    .valueSeq();
};
```

> > edit:
> >     I found an even better function: .update(). It's chainable and takes a custom function as an argument. The custom function gets the collection as argument and should return the collection as well (in my use case).
> >     https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Collection/update

New example:

```
export const selectCompletedFilesForSaveToServer = state => {
  const peek = function(collection) {
    console.log(collection.toJS());
    return collection;
  };

  return state
    .getIn(['file', 'saveToServerQueue'])
    .update(peek);
    .filterNot(item => item.get('isPosting'))
    .update(peek);
    .valueSeq();
};
```